# Ionic - How I get the date from next week?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to get today's date + 7  days.
Today I get with
`public dateToday: string = new Date().toLocaleDateString('de-DE');`

On Google I found this:

```
this.dateOneWeek.setDate(this.dateOneWeek.getDate() + 7);
```

But it doesn´t work, the function `setDate()` and `getDate()` doesn´t exist.

So how I can solve the Problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can try as below:

```
public dateOneWeek: string = new Date((new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7))).toLocaleDateString('de-DE');
```

Or for simplicity you should do as follow:

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);

var dateOneWeek= date.toLocaleDateString('de-DE');
console.log(dateOneWeek);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing where you're declaring your `dateOneWeek` variable.

Provided you initialize your `dateOneWeek` variable with a Date datatype, you should be able.

```
var dateOneWeek = new Date();
dateOneWeek.setDate(dateOneWeek.getDate() + 7);
```

If you are working with strings you are doing in:

```
public dateToday: string = new Date().toLocaleDateString('de-DE');
```

Adding 7 won't make a difference since it's in a string format.

Answer (score 1):

I declared 'dateOneWeek' as a String

now I have...

```
public dateToday: string = new Date().toLocaleDateString('de-DE');
public dateOneWeek: any = new Date('de-DE');
```

... and it works! :)

My new code for other people who have the same problem:

```
public anyDate: any = new Date();
public dateNextWeek: string;

  constructor() {
    this.anyDate.setDate(this.anyDate.getDate() + 7);
    this.dateNextWeek  = this.anyDate.toLocaleDateString('de-DE');
  }
```

*Posted on behalf of OP*